# Sequelize set alias attributes name after join

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, node-modules

After a join operation among three models I received a valid result but I would rename the attributes generated by the join operation of the findAll

**Query:**

```
const orchards = await db.Area.findAll({
        include: [db.AreaCoordinate, db.Crop],
        attributes: ['id', 'name']
      });
```

**AreaCoordinate Model:**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var AreaCoordinate = sequelize.define('AreaCoordinate', {
    latitude: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: true
    },
    longitude: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        AreaCoordinate.belongsTo(models.Area, {foreignKey: 'areaId'});
      }
    }
  });

  return AreaCoordinate;
};
```

**Crop Model:**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var Crop = sequelize.define('Crop', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: true
    },
    lang: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        Crop.hasMany(models.Area, {foreignKey:'cropId'})
      }
    }
  });

  return Crop;
};
```

**Area Model:**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var Area = sequelize.define('Area', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        // example on how to add relations
        Area.belongsTo(models.Crop, {foreignKey: 'cropId'});
        Area.belongsTo(models.Orchard, {as: 'orchard'});
        Area.hasMany(models.AreaCoordinate, {foreignKey:'areaId'})
      }
    }
  });

  return Area;
};
```

I would receive from the query a JSON like this:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "status_message": "OK",
    "data": {
        "orchard": [
            {
                "name": "pantano",
                "coordinates": [
                    {
                        "id": 115,
                        "latitude": "1",
                        "longitude": "2",
                        "createdAt": "2017-08-29T12:03:11.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2017-08-29T12:03:11.000Z",
                        "areaId": 28
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 116,
                        "latitude": "1",
                        "longitude": "2",
                        "createdAt": "2017-08-29T12:03:11.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2017-08-29T12:03:11.000Z",
                        "areaId": 28
                    }
                ],
                "cropId": 10
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But what I receive is (look AreaCoordinates and Crop):

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "status_message": "OK",
    "data": {
        "orchard": [
            {
                "name": "pantano",
                "AreaCoordinates": [
                    {
                        "id": 115,
                        "latitude": "1",
                        "longitude": "2",
                        "createdAt": "2017-08-29T12:03:11.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2017-08-29T12:03:11.000Z",
                        "areaId": 28
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 116,
                        "latitude": "1",
                        "longitude": "2",
                        "createdAt": "2017-08-29T12:03:11.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2017-08-29T12:03:11.000Z",
                        "areaId": 28
                    }
                ],
                "Crop": 10
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to set some alias for **AreaCoordinates** and **Crop** but I couldn't find a solution. Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 30):

Write query like this:

```
const result = await Table.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', ['foo', 'bar']] //id, foo AS bar
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default in Sequelize association, it will set the attribute name as the related model name. For your case, the related model named **AreaCoordinates**, so the attribute name in return will be **AreaCoordinates.** You should use *as*. Modify yours and Try this:

###findAll Query:

```
const orchards = await db.Area.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: db.AreaCoordinate,
            as: 'coordinates'
        }, {
            model: db.Crop,
            as: 'cropId',
            attributes: ['id']
        }],
    attributes: ['id', 'name']
});
```

###Area Model

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Area = sequelize.define('Area', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
        // example on how to add relations
            Area.belongsTo(models.Crop, {
                foreignKey: 'cropId',
                as: 'cropId'
            });
            Area.belongsTo(models.Orchard, {as: 'orchard'});
            Area.hasMany(models.AreaCoordinate, {
                foreignKey:'areaId',
                as: 'coordinates'
            })
        }
    }
});

return Area;
};
```